# Replace default template argument with alias

Tags: c++, templates

For a template with the following definition, The **'typename Container = std::deque'** seems to be the default template arguments. In this case can I just use alias instead?

```
template<typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T> >
class stack {
    // ...
}
```

Can I replace it with Alias?

```
template<typename T, typename C>
class stack {
    using Container = C<T>  // replace with alias
}
```

Updates:
I am curious about how to pass in a template param if C is a template. The answer below actually answers my question pretty well.

Comment: Provided that you use the correct syntax (`template <class> class C`), yes. But why?

Comment: @Quentin easier if I want to access the container type, no?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld You have to declare `C` as template template parameter, otherwise `C<T>` is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but the default template argument (i.e. `std::deque<T>`) is lost.

The more close one might be:

```
template<typename T, template <typename...> typename C = std::deque>
class stack {
    using Container = C<T>;  // replace with alias
    template <typename X>
    using Underlying_Container = C<X>; // an alias for C
};
```

Comment: in this case do you know how to access the type of Container for stack?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld Answer revised. Do you mean that?

Comment: no worries, forget about that :)